# Loop through mysql results and create array of unique times

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops

So I have a query which takes 6 times (these can be blank and so should be ignored) from a database and I want to loop through the results and pick out one of each of the times and order them in ascending order. So far I don't actually get a result when trying to echo this code out.

```
$rndQuery=$this->DB->prepare("select time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6 
                                from customers
                                where customer_cycle_uid=".$this->DB->quote_smart($cycleRow['uid'])."
                                    and customer_uid=".$this->DB->quote_smart($customerRow['uid'])."
                                    and (blistered='1')
                                    and (prn!='1')");
    $rndResult=$this->DB->query($rndQuery);
    $rndCount=$this->DB->numRows($rndResult);
    $rounds = array();

    while($rndRow=$this->DB->fetchArray($rndResult))
    {
        $rounds = array_merge($rounds, array_unique(array_filter($rndRow)));    
    }
    $rvalues = array_values($rounds);
```

I'm trying to end up with an array of times for example, 0700, 1200, 1500, 1800, 2200. It should be noted that if there are more than 6 different times this will create more than 6 array entities.

Comment: anyone? sadly I need this asap

Comment: Do you _want_ it to give you an array of more than 6 elements?

Comment: I want it to give me what is in the database, the customers entries have time1-time6 each of these could be different for all care I just need one of each in an array

Comment: why don't you do it in mysql?

Comment: can you give me a working code example? then I can tick it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is returning you the rows you want, here's some PHP to do the sorting part:

```
$rounds = array();
while($rndRow=$this->DB->fetchArray($rndResult)) {
    sort($rndRow);
    $rounds[] = array_unique($rndRow);
}
```